# Which Blockchain Do These Addresses (Starting With E) Belong To?

Tags: blockchain, wallets, addresses, explorers, explorer-api

I apologize for posting in the Ethereum site, since I know this isn't related to Ethereum. However, I'm really not sure which site to post in because that's the problem I have. There doesn't seem to be any sort of generic cryptocurrency site and I don't know which blockchain these addresses are associated with. I didn't want to post on cryptography or bitcoin because I figured I'd face an even worse reception there. (Ethereum users understand cryptocurrency and proponents are much more likely to acknowledge that there are other useful blockchains out there. If there's a better place I should post please let me know.)

I can't seem to find any way of determining which blockchain these wallets apply to. Most sources will only have a few different wallets and even the list of [supported withdrawal addresses from Kraken](https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001474826-Supported-address-formats-for-cryptocurrency-withdrawal) isn't helping.

Here are three addresses which are supposedly blockchain addresses, but I haven't been given any information on which blockchain they apply to.

```
Eb5Q2M8nJH9CnjCHCtZhi22hKARtdD5dJz
Ed7sdPNETw3Lj7a2KTcpqjGry8ZgYcMNyU
ELQuDNFySiFn4VsKqZuVJNB2rBbUNdnyf4
```

I'd like to look up the history of what happened to these wallets on a blockchain explorer, but the post that was describing these addresses literally doesn't mention the chain. Every attempt I've made to look up on bitcoin, ethereum, solana, elastos, etc... are all showing no results found, so I know if isn't one of those. I went through the whole list on Kraken and literally dozens of other sites I found on Google trying to get help. I just can't figure out what chain it is.

Really hope someone can help. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the addresses:

- have a length of **exactly 34 characters**, and
- have the **same leading symbol "E"**, and
- are [Base58Check](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding) encoded

You can make an educated guess that these are Bitcoin-style [**Pay-to-Public-Key-Hash (P2PKH)** or **Pay-to-Script-Hash (P2SH)** addresses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Invoice_address).

Assuming the mystery blockchain derives addresses the same way Bitcoin does, the prefix "E" implies a [hardcoded byte prefix (or "version byte")](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes) of **33 (`0x21`)**.

[Ian Coleman's BIP39 tool](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) retains [a list of the version bytes used by many blockchains](https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39/blob/master/src/js/bitcoinjs-extensions.js).

From the list, you can find the following blockchains derive a P2PKH address beginning with "E" (i.e., these blockchains have the key/value `pubKeyHash: 0x21` in the list):

- einsteinium
- europecoin
- exclusivecoin
- energi
- elastos

You can see these blockchains' P2PKH addresses under the "BIP44" tab using Ian Coleman's tool.

The following blockchains derive a P2SH address beginning with "E" (i.e., these blockchains have the key/value `scriptHash: 0x21` in the list):

- viacoin
- verge

You can see these blockchains' P2SH addresses under the "BIP49" tab using Ian Coleman's tool.

Of course, it's possible that the blockchain you're looking for is not on the list, or it uses a completely different address derivation scheme. But maybe this can help you get started in the right direction.